# Neo4JClient read all the properties of a node

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I am using Neo4jClient on my ASP.Net c# project to query and get data from the neo4j server. I can see that neo4j itself allows us to have various nodes of same type have different set of properties defined on them.

e.g. an Person Node can have  {Name, Age, Sex, Country} as a common field but some of them can also have additional properties like {Profession, EducationLevel, Title}.

So I was wondering if there is a way I can read all the properties of the node in a single query where it returns the properties as Key-value pair or any other such means so that I don't have to define classes for each combination.

Regards
Kiran

Answer (score 0):

It is in the Incoming list of functions, but I don't know the progress for this :

https://trello.com/c/FciCdgWl/7-cypher-property-container-functions

Answer (score 0):

this feature is still missing, which is quiet bad. a possible workaround could be to know all properties you have ever used ( `{allYourProps}` ), and send them as a parameter like:

```
START n=node(*)
WHERE filter( node in n WHERE all( prop in {allYourProps} WHERE has(node[prop])))
RETURN n;
```

[source](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/1696)